# How to configure Splunk forwarder to collect data from stdout/stderr instead of from files?

Tags: splunk

I have a **Splunk** forwarder configured to read my application server log files and send them to our indexer. That works just fine.

I'd like to re-configure my forwarder to read my logs directly from the standard output to reduce I/O overhead, can anyone help with that please?

Comment: It's always a good idea to put some code/commands that you already tried.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you calculate how much time its taking at the moment for the I/O overhead? Haven't heard anyone complain on performance for forwarders reading from files. If you're logging everything then perhaps you may get some value by filtering the server logs you're most interested in. This will also save you the I/O

Answer (score 0):

Forwarders cannot read from stdin.  They are designed to read files, but also read from TCP or UDP ports.  Accepting data on a port is not recommended because any time the forwarder restarts data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can used named pipes to create an in-memory 'file' that you can direct stdout and stderr to, and then have Splunk read those pipes.

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.5/Data/MonitorFIFOqueues

Note the caveats around this approach. If you are having issues with IO, I would suggest you address those issue first, before resorting to FIFO approaches.